# Ask the rule of Sigma infinite series

Tags: calculus, summation

Suppose I have an infinite sum series $\Sigma_{x=1}^\infty \frac{-(1-p)^x}{\log p}$, p is between 0 and 1. I am confident that I can factor $\frac{-1}{\log p}$ out, since this term is positive. But can I factor our a negative term out? For example, can I put $\frac{1}{\log p}$ out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $$\sum_k c\cdot a_k = c \sum_k a_k$$ even if $c<0$.